# Lotus notes view to display first 10 documents from another view

Tags: view, lotus-notes

I have a view (say A) with 50 documents, now I want another view (say B) to show only first 10 documents from view A. Is it possible through view selection formula?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this with only the selection formula. All solutions require running an agent, because view selection formulas can't do any lookups that refer to other views. The agent can run nightly, hourly, or whenever a document is added or modified in the database.

The most direct way would be to make B a folder instead of a view, and write an agent that walks view A to find the first ten documents and adds them to folder B, keeping track as it goes along. Then it walks the documents in folder B and removes any that are no longer currently in the top ten.

If you need to stick with a view for some reason, then you will need your agent to mark the first 10 documents in view A with a field value - e.g., Top10inA = 1. It will also have to clear that value from any other documents that used to have it. Then you can set up your view B with the formula SELECT Top10inA = l.

Answer (score 0):

No. Views don't allow you to select just the top N documents to be displayed.

What you can do is write a scheduled agent to either:

a) Loop through all the documents in view A and set an item named "SortOrder". Then set the selection formula on view B to show only documents with SortOrder <= 10

b) Loop through the documents in view A and move the first 10 documents to another folder B (instead of a view)